# Unable to use spring.security.core tags in Grails

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security, pom.xml

I'm currently working on a project which involves Spring (1.3.5), Grails (2.4.3) and Maven. I'm trying to use the tag `<sec:ifSwitched>` which belong to spring-security-core (2.0.0) in a GSP. The tag that I'm trying to use is not correctly rendered, but instead, inspecting the page, it renders `<sec:ifswitched>message</sec:ifswitched>`. I have already checked the dependencies in the pom.xml, and Maven downloads the resources. It seems like that I have missed something at the configuration level between Spring and Grails, any ideas?

I was trying to render correctly the tag `<sec:ifswitched>message</sec:ifswitched>`. I've tried to change the project's pom.xml and the .groovy file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end we came up with a solution: we have added `<Resource>grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityTagLib</Resource>` in the grails.xml file and finally marked the classed where those tags are used with the annotation `@TagLib`